# Anagram with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

```
const myAnagram = (arr1, arr2) => {
  let str1 = arr1;
  let str2 = arr2;
  let temp1 = [];
  let temp2 = [];
  let flag = 0;

  if (str1.length !== str2.length) return "Not Anagram statement A";

  for (var i = 0; i < str1.length - 1; i++) {
    temp1[i] = str1[i];
  }

  for (var j = 0; j < str2.length - 1; j++) {
    temp2[i] = str2[i];
  }

  temp1.sort();
  temp2.sort();

  for (var k = 0; k < str1.length - 1; k++) {
    if (temp1[j] !== temp2[j]) return "Not Anagram statement C";
    return "Anagram! statement D";
  }
}
```

Comment: Are your inputs strings or arrays ?

Comment: and you mean to iplement an [palindorme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palindrome) algorithm or anagram ? @Axel

Comment: @DanIonescu my inputs are strings sir, and implementing anagram only sir. thanks for your comment sir :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is with the identifiers you have used in loops.
Have a look at the corrected code.

```
function myAnagram(arr1, arr2) {

    var str1 = arr1;
    var str2 = arr2;
    var temp1 = [];
    var temp2 = [];
    var flag = 0;
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) {
        return "Not Anagram statement A";
    } else {
        for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; i++) {
            temp1[i] = str1[i];
        }

        for (var j = 0; j < str2.length; j++) {
            temp2[j] = str2[j];
        }
        temp1.sort();
        temp2.sort();
        for (var k = 0; k < str1.length; k++) {
            if (temp1[k] !== temp2[k]) {
                return "Not Anagram statement C";
            } else {
                return "Anagram! statement D";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps !! 
    PS: You can optimize this code to a great extend.

Comment: hi mate ! thanks for the explanation, i will try right now. thanks! :D gbu

Answer (score 1):

find two strings are equal size
compare the characters and the count of characters matches

```
const isAnagram = (str1, str2) => {
   const compare = (first, next) => {
    return first.split('').sort().join('') === next.split('').sort().join('');
   }
   return str1.length !== str2.length ? false : compare(str1, str2);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loops always skip the last elements since you use `<` together with `str1.length - 1`. You should either use 
`for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i) {...}` or 
`for (var i = 0; i <= str.length-1; ++i) {...}`

Furthermore in your comparison loop you already return when the first characters match (or when they don't). Therefore the loop will never compare the second (or nth) characters. The loop should further compare the characters until you are sure the arrays differ at some point.

You can shrink the function like

```
function isAnagram(str1, str2) {
    if (str1.length !== str2.length) return false

    var arr1 = arr2 = []
    for (var i = 0; i < str1.length; ++i) {
        arr1[i] = str1[i]
        arr2[i] = str2[i]
    }

    arr1.sort()
    arr2.sort()

    for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; ++i)
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) return false
    return true
}
```

And then

```
if (isAnagram("frog","rg0f")) {
    console.log("Anagram!")
} else {
    console.log("Not Anagram.")
}
```

Comment: hi @mmende, thanks for your help and explanation, now i know wheres the problem is. btw thank you very much mate! gbu !.